# How to build a case-insensitive regular expression with Regexp.union

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a list of strings, and need to build the regular expression from them, using [`Regexp#union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union). I need the resulting pattern to be *case insensitive*.

The `#union` method itself does not accept options/modifiers, hence I currently see two options:

```
strings = %w|one two three|

Regexp.new(Regexp.union(strings).to_s, true)
```

and/or:

```
Regexp.union(*strings.map { |s| /#{s}/i })
```

Both variants look a bit weird.

Is there an ability to construct a case-insensitive regular expression by using `Regexp.union`?

Comment: Note that your first option `Regexp.new(Regexp.union(strings).to_s, true)` returns `/(?-mix:one|two|three)/i` which is probably not what you want, because the words are still matched case sensitive (`-i`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simple starting place is:

```
words = %w[one two three]
/#{ Regexp.union(words).source }/i # => /one|two|three/i
```

You *probably* want to make sure you're only matching words so tweak it to:

```
/\b#{ Regexp.union(words).source }\b/i # => /\bone|two|three\b/i
```

For cleanliness and clarity I prefer using a non-capturing group:

```
/\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(words).source })\b/i # => /\b(?:one|two|three)\b/i
```

Using [`source`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#method-i-source) is important. When you create a Regexp object, it has an idea of the flags (`i`, `m`, `x`) that apply to that object and those get interpolated into the string:

```
"#{ /foo/i }" # => "(?i-mx:foo)"
"#{ /foo/ix }" # => "(?ix-m:foo)"
"#{ /foo/ixm }" # => "(?mix:foo)"
```

or

```
(/foo/i).to_s  # => "(?i-mx:foo)"
(/foo/ix).to_s  # => "(?ix-m:foo)"
(/foo/ixm).to_s  # => "(?mix:foo)"
```

That's fine when the generated pattern stands alone, but when it's being interpolated into a string to define other parts of the pattern the flags affect each sub-expression:

```
/\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(words) })\b/i # => /\b(?:(?-mix:one|two|three))\b/i
```

Dig into the Regexp documentation and you'll see that `?-mix` turns off "ignore-case" inside `(?-mix:one|two|three)`, even though the overall pattern is flagged with `i`, resulting in a pattern that doesn't do what you want, and is really hard to debug:

```
'foo ONE bar'[/\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(words) })\b/i] # => nil
```

Instead, `source` removes the inner expression's flags making the pattern do what you'd expect:

```
/\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(words).source })\b/i # => /\b(?:one|two|three)\b/i
```

and

```
'foo ONE bar'[/\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(words).source })\b/i] # => "ONE"
```

You *can* build your patterns using `Regexp.new` and passing in the flags:

```
regexp = Regexp.new('(?:one|two|three)', Regexp::EXTENDED | Regexp::IGNORECASE) # => /(?:one|two|three)/ix
```

but as the expression becomes more complex it becomes unwieldy. Building a pattern using string interpolation remains more easy to understand.

Comment: That's interesting. It didn't occur to me that `"Twosome" =~ /\b#{ Regexp.union(words).source }\b/i #=> 0`. Hence the need to put `#{ Regexp.union(words).source }` in a group. Nor did I know about `source`.

Comment: `source`, of course, thanks! Great explanation, btw.

Comment: I use a lot of patterns for parsing text, and `source` was core to being able to combine simple patterns into more complex ones.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057658/how-to-embed-regular-expressions-in-other-regular-expressions-in-ruby has more information.

Answer (score 0):

You've overlooked the obvious.

```
strings = %w|one two three|

r = Regexp.union(strings.flat_map do |word| 
  len = word.size
  (2**len).times.map { |n|
    len.times.map { |i| n[i]==1 ? word[i].upcase : word[i] } }
end.map(&:join))

 "'The Three Little Pigs' should be read by every building contractor" =~ r
   #=> 5
```

Comment: That would work, yes; even more: with properly patched `String#upcase` is will even work with _utf8_ strings, like with cyrillic (while standard Ruby regexps still lack this functionality.)

Comment: This an absurd answer. I'd downvote it if I could. Suppose `r` is the regex computed for `strings = ["one", "two", "three hundred seventy"]`. Sure, it works (`"There were tHRee HuNDred sevENTy cats" =~ r #=> 11`), but `r.to_s.count('|') #=> 2097167`!

Comment: I know, I know ;) I am not going to use it in prod, only at home.

Comment: TIL that one can use index access to get bits from an integer :tada: