# How to iterate through a hash and an array and replace words in strings

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, iterator

I'm trying to iterate through an array of strings and replace the words if they match any of the substitution rules:

```
array= ["I love chicken!", "I love lamb!", "I love beef!"]
substitutions = {
"love" => "hate",
"lamb" => "turkey"
}
```

I want to iterate through the array and check for any words that match with the keys within the substitutions hash. The array would then become:

```
array= ["I hate chicken!", "I hate turkey!", "I hate beef!"]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
array.each do |strings|
strings = strings.split
    strings.each do |word|
        substitutions.each do |phrase,substitute|
            if word == phrase
                word = substitute
                return word
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the result you need. As you may see, you are overcomplicating a bit

```
arry= ["I love chicken!", "I love lamb!", "I love beef!"]
substitutions = { "love" => "hate", "lamb" => "turkey" }

arry.each_with_index do |str,ind|
  substitutions.each_key do |word|
    arry[ind].gsub!(word,substitutions[word]) if str.include?(word)
  end
end

puts arry
```

This will give you:

```
[ "I hate chicken!", "I hate turkey!", "I hate beef!" ]
```

Your strategy of spliting the sentences wouldn't work. The exclamation marks would create some trouble. The idea of testing with `#include?` is much better in this case.

And notice the use of `gsub!` (with the !), which will make the changes in the original array.

Comment: No need to define the keys-array `words`. Iterate over the `substitutions` hash with [Hash#each_key](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Hash.html#method-i-each_key)

Answer (score 1):

```
arr  = ["I love chicken!", "I love lamb!", "I love beef!"]
subs = { "love"=>"hate", "lamb"=>"turkey" }

subs.default_proc = ->(h,k) { k }
  #=> #<Proc:0x007f9ff0a014b8@(irb):1343 (lambda)>
arr.map { |s| s.gsub(/\w+/, subs) }
  #=> ["I hate chicken!", "I hate turkey!", "I hate beef!"]
```

I used [Hash#default_proc=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) to attach a proc to `subs` so that `subs[k]` returns `k` if `subs` does not have a key `k` and used the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that employs a hash for making substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to iterate over the hash at all. Instead use it to generate a regular expression and pass it to `gsub`. Here's how I've done it many times; It's the basis for a templating engine:

```
array = ["I love chicken!", "I love lamb!", "I love beef!"]
substitutions = {
  "love" => "hate",
  "lamb" => "turkey"
}

key_regex = /\b(?:#{Regexp.union(substitutions.keys).source})\b/
# => /\b(?:love|lamb)\b/

array.map! { |s|
  s.gsub(key_regex, substitutions)
}

array # => ["I hate chicken!", "I hate turkey!", "I hate beef!"]
```

If you don't want to munge the contents of `array` use `map` instead, which will return a new array leaving the original untouched:

```
array.map { |s|
  s.gsub(key_regex, substitutions)
}
# => ["I hate chicken!", "I hate turkey!", "I hate beef!"]

array # => ["I love chicken!", "I love lamb!", "I love beef!"]
```

The trick is defining the regular expression used to find the key words.

See "[How to build a case-insensitive regular expression with Regexp.union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150519/how-to-build-a-case-insensitive-regular-expression-with-regexp-union/38154742#38154742)" along with the [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) documenation for more information.